# Spring webmvc chaining viewresolvers gives BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException

Tags: java, spring

I have a simple (sample) web application that i have a problem with if i try chaining multiple viewresolvers. When my application is configured in the way described below, trying to access `http://localhost:8080/Library/spring/initApplication` will throw the error described below.

It seems as though the InitApplication is erroneously being picked up by the wrong view resolver. If i change the order of the view resolvers everything works, but im still wondering why exactly this error occurs because i cant pinpoint why it happens. Im guessing a configuration issue?

```
26027 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Could not complete request
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'initApplication' must be of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.View], but was actually of type [library.controller.InitApplication]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:266)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1079)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver.loadView(ResourceBundleViewResolver.java:196)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.createView(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.resolveViewName(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.resolveViewName(DispatcherServlet.java:1078)
```

Details of the important files:
InitApplication.java

```
@Controller
public class InitApplication {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/initApplication", method = RequestMethod.GET)
etc.......
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>testwebproj</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/spring/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

springmvc-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="order" value="2" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/library" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <!-- <property name="password" value="" /> -->
    </bean>

    <bean id="myEmf"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
    </bean>


<bean id="pdfViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="basename" value="views" />
</bean>


<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<context:component-scan base-package="library"></context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

views.properties

```
pdfPrinter.(class)=library.controller.DummyController
```

Comment: have you tried renaming your bean?  You may be clobbering an internal bean used by spring

Comment: I renamed the InitApplication class to something else, and it works! VERY strange. Im going to see if i can find out in debug mode what is going on internally, but at least the mystery is more or less solved. Thanks for the tip. Its still a bit shady why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly because your are mapping your view with a Controller class mate!

```
pdfPrinter.(class)= you should indicate a View class here!
```

For example to map a Controller to a jsp View, you will need to proceed like this:

```
login.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView
login.url=/vues/en/login.jsp
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried renaming your bean? You may be clobbering an internal bean used by spring